# Swapping First Two Letters of a word in a phrase in c++

Tags: c++

How do I make the for loop swap the first two characters of every word in a phrase?

```
int main() {
 cout << "Enter a phrase" << endl;
 char phrase[30];
 cin.get(phrase, 30);
 int temp;
 for (int i = 0; i < strlen(phrase); i++) {
  for (int j = i+1; j < strlen(phrase); j++) {
      int k = j+1;
      //Start of for loop
      if (i == 0 && j == 1) {
          phrase[i] = temp;
          phrase[i] = phrase[j];
          phrase[j] = temp;
      }
      if (phrase[i] == '\0' || phrase[i] == 0) {
       phrase[j] = temp;
       phrase[j] = phrase[k];
       phrase[k] = temp;

      }
  }
 }
cout << phrase << endl;
}
```

When I input "Hello world" I get "ePllo World" as a result

Comment: Or am I doing it right? Sometimes my computer doesn't compile C++ code correctly so I don't know. Also, I have to use for loops and char arrays, please don't recommend any solutions using swap() or anything like that. Thanks!

Comment: If you'd use `std::swap` you'd avoid the typographic mistake in your code.  (Hint: How many time to you read from `temp`, and how many times to you write to it?)

Comment: I'm not allowed to use std::swap for this problem

Comment: Then think about the hint.

Comment: The swapping is implemented VERY incorrectly.     In the loops,  `temp` is uninitialised, so `phrase[i] = temp` or `phrase[j] = temp` (whichever comes first) has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ah thank you, I have to do temp = phrase[i] first. However, for                        
 if (phrase[i] == '\0' || phrase[i] == 0) {
       temp=phrase[j]
       phrase[j] = phrase[k];
       phrase[k] = temp;         the first two letters of the words aren't changing, am I checking for a blank space incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-First, you can change your if statement with the condition if your loop at the first character in the phrase and meets a space.

-Second, you can change how the way you swap from this :

```
  phrase[i] = temp;
  phrase[i] = phrase[j];
  phrase[j] = temp;
```

with this :

```
 temp = phrase[i];
 phrase[i] = phrase[j];
 phrase[j] = temp;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Am I checking for blank spaces wrong though, when input Hello there I get eHllo there, the first world changes, but the second one doesn't, and I executed the swap correctly/

Comment: You can check if there's a space by phrase[i] == ' '

Comment: Try phrase[i] == 32 , 32 from the ASCII number of space

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I'm still having difficulty with changing the first two letters of the second word. My changed code is if (phrase[i] == 32) {
       temp = phrase[j];
       phrase[j] = phrase[k];
       phrase[k] = temp;
          
      } (with k being j+1) and when I input hello there I get ehllo here, phrase[j] is being removed for some reason

Comment: I think you just need to do 
if (phrase[i] == 32) { temp = phrase[i+1]; phrase[i+1] = phrase[i+2]; phrase[i+2] = temp; }

Answer (score 1):

This one is pretty easy!

You're on the right track. When you cin your phrase, you can immediately switch the 1st index with the 2nd. Then, you for loop thru the rest. Something like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1ntj.png

Comment: This answer does not add anything to the ones already available.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! This would have been a lot more useful a year and 3 months ago, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proper C++ way of doing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string phrase;

    std::cout << "Enter a phrase" << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, phrase);

    std::stringstream ss{phrase};

    std::string reversedPhrase;
    std::string word;

    while (ss >> word) {
        std::swap(word[0], word[word.length() - 1]);
        reversedPhrase += word + " ";
    }

    std::cout << "Original phrase: " << phrase << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Reversed phrase: " << reversedPhrase << std::endl;
}
```

You can play around with the code live [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1Mjb46YY3uVbKCPk)

Comment: Thank you, but in my comment under my post I said that I had to use for loops.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't see your comment. Do you want me to remove my answer?